# Get my TV to work with 2 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, tv, dvi

I'm using the [Club Radeon HD 6950 2GB](http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/radeon-hd-6950.621.html) graphics card. It has 2 DVI ports as well as a single HDMI port. My 2 monitors are connected through the DVI ports and I put them on extended background so I can simply go from one screen to another. Now I was wondering if I could use my (huge) TV screen as another passive screen. I would only use it for watching movies on so it does not have to be used at the same time as my monitors however I don't want to keep disconnection the monitors in order to use my TV. I know this is possible as there are other posts on here however my TV is pretty big (50 inch) so I think we can rule out the same graphic settings. Anything I have to buy in order to get this to work?

**To sum it up :**
I want to have both my monitors and TV connected at the same time while not needing to use all 3 at the same time I want to be able to use my TV without having to disconnect any cables. I don't mind purchasing equipment.

My [ASRock P67 Pro3 motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/P67%20Pro3/) does not support multiple graphics cards.

Comment: As a current "fix" i got it working separately. (I got both monitors currently connected) I turn 1 off in the screen resolution settings. Then i set my remaining monitor on duplicate with the tv. Then turn the other monitor off and voila you have the tv as main screen. This is not the solution to my question however but it works temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Just buy a HDMI-cable and connect it to your graphic card.
Souldn't be a problem?! You can configure and control all the monitors through your **ATI Catalyst Control Center**.

Comment: this would indeed work but as already stated the graphics card does not support 3 screens at once and my tv's size does not allow duplication of one of the screens.

Comment: to elaborate my previous answer, if i try to connect my tv through the control center one of my other screens turns off proving that i cant use more then 2 screens at once.

Answer (score 0):

You motherboard will support multiple graphics adapters fine.  Just maybe not 2 PCIe 16x cards.

Consider obtaining a [PCIe 1x video adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007709%20600007854&IsNodeId=1&name=PCI%20Express%20x1), or get a [DisplayLink USB video adapter](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters) and be done. :)